# Why docker expose is enabled by default?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

> File: Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

ENV NODE_CUSTOM_PORT 3000

WORKDIR /

COPY . .

RUN npm install

ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]
```

I did not **EXPOSE** any port on Dockerfile, but still If I ping this container **IP:PORT** from another container I can access my node application. I have checked [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose) but there is nowhere mentioned that it will be enabled by default.

docker build and run command I performed

`docker build -t myhello:2 .`

`docker run myhello:2`

> UPDATE:

It is not happening when docker run with `-d`

But I can confirm it is happening when run without it `-d`

Comment: The `EXPOSE` in the Dockerfile doesn’t mean anything apart from acting as a documentation - just like the `MAINTAINER`. Did you read the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Expose" mostly doesn't have any effect in modern Docker.  If you have a container IP address and you can reach it at all, then you can reach any port being served within the container, regardless of whether it's formally "exposed" or not.

---

"Expose" – either via the Dockerfile `EXPOSE` directive, the `docker run --expose` option, or the Docker Compose `expose:` setting – does two things:

1. If you `docker run -P` (capital "P") your image, Docker will publish all exposed ports, on arbitrarily chosen host ports, to all interfaces.
2. If you are using the outdated `docker run --link` option, then Docker will create [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#environment-variables) based on the exposed ports in the container you're linking to.

You do not need to "expose" a port to connect to it from outside.  From other containers, [connect them to the same Docker-internal network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#connect-a-container-to-a-user-defined-bridge), which makes their container names available as hostnames, and you can connect to ports that servers inside containers are actually running on, exposed or not.  (Docker Compose [does this setup automatically](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).)  From outside container space, use the `docker run -p` option to publish ports, and they can be accessed via the mapped port on the host's IP address.

(Neither of these paths need the container-private IP address, and in fact these addresses are unusable in a variety of common situations.  Manually looking them up isn't usually necessary, and you should treat them as an implementation detail.)

Comment: I was told recently that, if an image `EXPOSE`s a port, and you try to launch it in Docker Desktop, then you'll be prompted to publish that port in the container startup options.  The metadata has always been in the image (`docker inspect` will show it) and so it's possible that tools can take advantage of it; the Docker Desktop support is new since I originally wrote this answer.

Comment: Yes, this is right, @David Maze. I just tried with Docker Desktop, and it implements the Host Port text area as soon as I added an explicit EXPOSE statement in the Dockerfile before rebuilding the image.